# Navigation From One View Controller to Another

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8.3

I am a .Net Developer and just started my first iOS project using swift. I want to navigate from one view controller to another using code. Like we do in WP 8.1 with the help of following code:

```
Frame.Navigate(Typeof("Page_2"));
```

Comment: You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75625154/16403924).  Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way that you can do it depending on how you are calling or executing the code.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your destination view controller an identifier (in storyboard).  Then, put this into the view controller you're navigating from...

```
let controller = self.sender.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("resultController") as! ResultController
controller.myViewModel= myViewModel!
self.sender.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: i gave it the identifier resultController but there are 2 errors in this code. I am putting this code behind a button.