# InstantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting this error - InstantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer

To solve this problem I had to use a condition like this:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

}
```

But how to solve this problem without this condition.

My code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
        vc?.bookNameToSend = bookName[indexPath.row]
        vc?.bookImageToSend = bookImage[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 5:
Without checking iOS version, you can add navigation functionalities. To make it more easier, you need to add some methods as extension and a singleton method.

Firstly you need to add those method as extension for common use -->

```swift
extension UIStoryboard {
    enum Storyboard: String {
        case yourStoryboard  = "StoryboardName"  // your targeted storyboard name
    }
    
    // MARK: - Convenience Initializers
    convenience init(storyboard: Storyboard, bundle: Bundle? = nil) {
        self.init(name: storyboard.rawValue, bundle: bundle)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Class Functions
    class func storyboard(_ storyboard: Storyboard, bundle: Bundle? = nil) -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: storyboard.rawValue, bundle: bundle)
    }
    
    // MARK: - View Controller Instantiation from Generics
    func instantiateViewController<T>(withIdentifier identifier: T.Type) -> T where T: StoryboardIdentifiable {
        let className = String(describing: identifier)
        weak var weakSelf = self
        guard let vc =  weakSelf?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: className) as? T else {
            fatalError("Cannot find controller with identifier \(className)")
        }
        return vc
    }
}
```

Secondly add a swift file and create a singleton method -->

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class NavigationManager {
    static let shared = NavigationManager()
    init() { }
    
    func navigateToTargetVC<T: UIViewController>(storyboard: UIStoryboard.Storyboard, viewControllerName: T.Type, navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(storyboard: storyboard)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName.self)
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Then in your project, you can call this singleton method in any view or viewController to make navigation like -->

```swift
private func goToYourTargetedViewController(){
        NavigationManager.shared.navigateToTargetVC(storyboard: .yourStoryboard, viewControllerName: YourTargetedViewControllerName.self, navigationController: self.navigationController ?? UINavigationController())
    }
```

Now call this private method `goToYourTargetedViewController()` whenever you want to navigate to your targeted viewController.

Answer (score 12):

In iOS 13, Apple has introduced this new method `instantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)` which creates confusement, but the old method still exists.

So use `instantiatViewController(withIdentifier:)` instead.

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CartViewController") as? CartViewController
```

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 13 the parameter name is `identifier` and below iOS 13 version the parameter name is  `withIdentifier`

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "doctorProfileVC") as DrProfileViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    } else {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboard.instantiateViewController") as! DrProfileViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to solve that problem is to change the project minimum target version to iOS 13 or avoid using that specific method, otherwise you'll have to use the if condition.

Comment: But sometimes we have to give support to those old devices whose versions are below iOS 13.